# Multiple if statements and corresponding emails -- possible to put all in one function?

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't seem to get multiple if statements to play together nicely. I don't think *if/else if* works, I've not had luck with nesting ifs, and I can't figure out whether *if/and if* is a thing or not.

**Pseudocode below:**

- If date criteria 1 met, send email version 1,  AND
- If date criteria 2 met, send email version 2, AND
- If date criteria 3 met, send email version 3....etc

**Current code for one if statement and email version below. Not sure how/where to put all the other if statements and corresponding HTML messages so that they ALL get run.**

```
function autoEmails(){
   
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  
      var range = sheet.getDataRange();
      var values = range.getDisplayValues();  
      var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
      var count = ss.getRange("A1:Y"+lastRow+"").getValues();
      var message = "";
      

for (x=0; x<count.length; x++)  
      if (values[x][18] == 'TRUE') //  This is date condition #1 that checks against a cell in the sheet
        
    {
      var row = count[x];
      var caseName = row[1];
      var worker = row[2];
      var courtType = row[3];
      var courtStart = row[4];
      var courtEnd = row[5];
      var dueCourt = row[7];
      var dueSupervisor = row[6];
      var dueAdoptionProgressReport = row[9];
      var dueAdminPanelReview = row[10];
      var description = row[11];
      var options = {
          'description': description,
          'guests': worker +',',
          'sendInvites': 'True',
      };

          
        message = "blah blah blah";
                       
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: worker,
          cc: 'SampleEmail@gmail.com',
          subject: 'Reminder: FC Plan due to Supervisor in 7 days (' + caseName + ')',
          htmlBody: message});

      }
```

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: What are the second and third conditions you want to verify. And why didn't nesting `if`s work? Did you try using "&&"?

Comment: Hi @Aerials - I don't need to build an if statement that has many conditions so I don't believe nesting ifs is appropriate...I want the script to send 3 different emails, based on 3 different dates. It is possible for all 3 conditions to be true and that 3 emails are to be sent.  So my 3 conditions are: (A) If date criteria 1 met, send email version 1, AND
(B) If date criteria 2 met, send email version 2, AND
(C) If date criteria 3 met, send email version 3....etc     (And grain of salt, I'm still a beginner with apps script...so I may be missing something very basic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an instruction is complete, the program moves to the next instruction. You can use as many `if` conditionals as you want.

```js
function sendEmail(conditions){
  // Check if condition A is met
  if(conditions[0] == "TRUE"){
    // Send Email A
    console.log("Email A sent because condition 0 was met");
  }
  if(conditions[1] == "TRUE"){
    // Send Email B
    console.log("Email B sent because condition 1 was met");
  }
  if(conditions[2] == "TRUE"){
    // Send Email C
    console.log("Email C sent because condition 2 was met");
  }
}
// Make a sample conditions object
let conditions = ["TRUE","TRUE","TRUE"];
// Send emails based on conditions 
sendEmail(conditions);
// What happens if only one condition isn't met?
conditions = ["FALSE","TRUE","TRUE"];
sendEmail(conditions);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! An elementary principle...but I think I was sticking in some extra brackets or semi-colons between the ifs when I was trying to do them sequentially and that was messing it all up. I got it to work as expected with your guidance. Really appreciate your time.